# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState happening only for a few users

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Note: Please note that this issue is happening only for one in thousand users and is not reproducible easily**

I have an application in Play store which works fine for most of the users but every now and then I get crash logs related to a peculiar issue.

```
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I assume this happens when I am trying to commit a fragment after `onSavedInstanceState()` has been called. But AFAIK, `onSavedInstanceState()` will be called after `onPause()` and I am doing fragment commit inside `onCreate()` of the activity

Here is the code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.arrow_dark_gray);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initFragments();

    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null){
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    }


//This function is called from onCreate method.
  private void initFragments() {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MyFragment = new MyFragment();


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(Constants.DATA, customAdapter);

    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.shopping_container, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
```

So clearly I am doing `commit()` inside `onCreate()`. Is it possible that during `onCreate()` `onSavedInstanceState()` is called sometimes due to some configuration changes or if the OS is low on memory. Thats why this crash is happening?

And would replacing `commit()` with `commitAllowingStateLoss()` be the best solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and `commitAllowingStateLoss()` works fine.

If you need more information, you can take a look to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345684/3742122