# Error occurs when you use the library com.android.support:design:23.1.1+ in Smart Lock sample app

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I downloaded the example of application [Smart Lock for passwords](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-smart-lock/#1) from Google.
Is there a solution other than the use of the library <= 23.0.1?

Bug in library?

Error occurs when you use the library com.android.support:design:23.1.1+:

```
03-31 09:53:18.828 16779-16779/com.google.codelab.smartlock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.codelab.smartlock, PID: 16779
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
at com.google.codelab.smartlock.MainActivity.setFragment (MainActivity.java:119)
at com.google.codelab.smartlock.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:37)
at com.google.codelab.smartlock.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:79)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

[FATAL EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v0zy.gif)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: calling `com.android.support:design:23.1.1+:` is not good approach ,You should avoid `+`

Comment: I mean "version of the library using above 23.0.1." Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example from Google I changed the following piece of code in MainActivity,java:

```
    private void setFragment(Intent intent) {
    ...
    if (currentTag == null || !currentTag.equals(tag)) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

To:

```
    private void setFragment(Intent intent) {
    ...
    if (currentTag == null || !currentTag.equals(tag)) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Android compileSdkVersion is the version of the compiler used in
> building the Application .The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs.

**For compileSdkVersion 23 You can use bellows**

Calling `+` is not good Approach

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little confused)
When I compile version 23.0.1 (compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' in build.gradle) - no errors.
When I compile 23.1.1 or 23.2.1 (compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' in build.gradle or 23.2.1) - an exception in app.. I`m not calling "+"

Comment: if `buildToolsVersion 23.0.1` then `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'//23.2.1` never work

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: i suggest try with `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Comment: It is also an exception

Comment: `.commitAllowingStateLoss();` oh That case .see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748398/what-is-the-difference-between-commit-and-commitallowingstateloss-in-fragments`

Comment: thanks. I found the solution just before) Yes, this is the case

Comment: @SergeyZhadan Move ahead .Happy coding