# Refreshing fragments on filter selection from parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this scenario where I have An Activity(A) which has 2 tabs (ie. two fragments FA1,FA2) . The appBar in Activity A has a filter button which opens different Activities(B & C) depending on which tab is selected. 
this has been handled by the following code in A.

```
  toolbar.findViewById(R.id.filterimage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = null;
            if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1) {
                i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);

            } else {
                i = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
            }
            startActivityForResult(i, 221);

        }
    });
```

all the api hits to show data in two fragments are made in the respective fragments. Filter which has been selected from Activity B or C is returned to activity A . 
Now depending on the filters selected I want to refresh the fragment(FA1 or FA2) again from it's parent activity ie. A. 
But I am unable to do so . 
How can I do this?

Comment: you can refresh fragments. You can have a link to those fragments in your activity, and call `fragment1.doSomething()`

Comment: @rajat44 You can refresh fragment on onResume() i guess, if you haven't tried that!!

Comment: what if I do 
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  ? 

OR 

 TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
                    tab.select();

Comment: Do you want to refresh the fragments when you return to Activity A after selecting a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

 // Where currentFragment is the fragment you want to refresh

 getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.detach(currentFragment)
.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();

 getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.attach(currentFragment)
.commitAllowingStateLoss();

 }
```

Here you have to check particular case when it comes from B or C activity, otherwise don't refresh.

Comment: It worked !! 
But what does above code do ? Can you please explain the code . 
Thanks!!

Comment: @rajat44 good to hear that, as name indicates using first 4 lines we detach your fragment and after that it attaches as if it loads at first time. and for commitAllowingStateLoss please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18345684/3117966) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Use different request code for both like below:

```
toolbar.findViewById(R.id.filterimage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = null;
        if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1) {
            i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 221);

        } else {
            i = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 222);
        }

    }
});
```

Then depends on request code get result and update fragments data.